# display a non configurable attribute of a configurable product on front end

Tags: magento

so for each simple product under a configurable product there is an attribute (for clarity here i'm going to call it "special attribute"), which is basically a description for that combination of configuration options. I'm not working with cars but as an example of my problem imagine you choose a cadillac in magento then choose what stereo, what color, what wheel type you want. This combination has a "special attribute" (as do all combinations) of "horizon edition" or "travellers edition" or whatever else that type is. some combinations have many lines describing for "special attribute". This won't work as a configurable attribute, if I put the information into a normal attribute I can see it in the backend but it won't be visible from the front end. Has anyone got any tips on whether this is straight forward, can use a plugin. I'm thinking I'm probably going to have to do it with json and jquery but pretty tight on time right now.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

An exact answer depends on your application. You may have noticed that the config option dropdown is built from JSON data which is rendered in `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`. The corresponding block class used to render this template is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`. You could bang your attribute into the JSON data by adding to the config attributes collection, but depending on your experience with Magento modeling and rewrites.

A possibly easier approach might be to grab the child products of the configurable and get the attribute info therefrom.

Answer (score 0):

Organic Internet - Simple Configurable Products extension does it for you. There is an extension to install for free on Connect and all the code is up on GitHub.